# How to display video one after another from Database in HTML5

Tags: php, html

I have a video table which contains (more than one) id and video_path. I want to play video one after another from the database using PHP in HTML5. note that I keep only video path in the table.

I am trying

**PHP**

```
    $connection...
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($controller)) {     
    $id = $row['id'];
    $url = $row['video_path'];
    $vdo = $_POST[$url];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<video id="custom_video_play" width="400" controls="controls" src="$vdo" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
</video>
```

my database query is working properly. I want to fix the code error only to watch video in web page.
if someone please help!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively call a play function which checks if the current video has ended, if it has it will get the next src path in your array.

```
    // Get the video of the element
    var video = $('#your_video_elem');
    var video_array; // get your array of video paths
    var n = 0;

    $(document).ready(function(){
         // Check if DOM is ready, if so play the first video.
        play_video();
    });

    function play_video() {
        if(video.get(0).ended) {
            video.attr('src', video_array[n]);
            n++;
            play_video();    // call recursively to get the next video
        } 
    }
```

The `play_video` method is called recursively only one the current video has ended, it loops through your array of video paths and updates the `src` of your video tag each time

Comment: what will be HTML code structure? Please note that my above code tested for single code so I need code structure me single and multiple video.